# How to safely add bool field to gRPC server struct?

Tags: go, grpc

I'm looking to add what's essentially a "status" boolean field to my gRPC Server.
The idea is that the state of the server could be set when certain conditions are met, so when any new gRPC requests come in, the response would be tailored accordingly.

I have a `server struct` that I'm using, and for this example, I've added a `HappyHour bool` field.
I have a goroutine that runs when the server is started, and every minute it checks the time of day. If the time of day is between 5-7pm, HappyHour gets set to true. Otherwise, it gets set to false.

```
type server struct {
    HappyHour bool
    mu     sync.RWMutex
}

func (s *server) OrderDrink(ctx context.Context, req *bar.DrinkRequest) (*flatbuffers.Builder, error) {

    drink := string(req.drink())
    qty := req.qty()


    // Code here to look up the price of the drink in the database
    total := price*qty

    // Use a mutex to check HappyHour status 
    s.mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RLock()
    if s.HappyHour == true {
        total=total/2
    }

    b := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(0)
    // Serialize the response and send it to the client
}


func main() {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:50051")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer(grpc.CustomCodec(flatbuffers.FlatbuffersCodec{}))

    var srv server
    bar.RegisterBARServer(s, &srv) 

    // Monitor happy hour
    go happyHour(&srv)
}
```

Things seem to be working from my initial testing, but I'm quite new to gRPC, and am a bit worried about using a mutex on the server struct.

Will there be negative performance impacts if there are many clients connecting to the server? If I'm reading or updating HappyHour, and the lock has been acquired, would this impact new users connecting or sending requests? Or would this only impact the actual `HappyHour` field?

Comment: One thing you can improve is to unlock immediately after checking, instead of using defer. Otherwise, it looks reasonable to me. There shouldn't be much performance impact for readers. When you're updating, all new readers will wait until all the existing readers are done and writer unlocks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out about unlocking immediately after, @bserdar. I've got it ingrained into my head to defer in case something goes wrong, but in this example there's no risk of that :)

Comment: Why don't just use some function "isHappyHour(time.Time)" which returns bool based on the given argument? The stateless is always safer than stateful.

Comment: @Mikhail - My real code is a bit more involved than my example, but I think that would still be a viable option for my needs. Thanks!